# Spark Map partiton not working in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am running a spark scala program for performing text scanning in input file. I am trying to achieve parallelism by using rdd.mappartition. Inside the mappartition section i am performing few checks and calling the map function to achieve parallel execution for each partition. Inside the map function i am calling a custom method where i am performing the scanning and sending the results back.

Now, the code is working fine when i submit the code using --master local[*] but the same is not working when i submit using --master yarn-cluster. It is working without any error but the call is not getting inside the mappartition itself.I verified this by placing few println statements.

Please help me with your suggestions.
Here is the sample code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val inputRdd = sc.textFile(inputFile,2)
  val resultRdd = inputRdd.mapPartitions{ iter =>

    println("Inside scanning method..")
    var scanEngine = ScanEngine.getInstance();
    ...
    ....
    ....
    var mapresult = iter.map { y =>
      line = y
      val last = line.lastIndexOf("|");
      message = line.substring(last + 1, line.length());
      getResponse(message)
    }
  }

  val finalRdd = sc.parallelize(resultRdd.map(x => x.trim()))
  finalRdd.coalesce(1, true).saveAsTextFile(hdfsOutpath)

}   

def getResponse(input: String): String = {
  var result = "";
  val rList = new ListBuffer[String]();

  try {
      //logic here
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: It is working but the logic written inside the mappartition is not getting executed when i run in --master yarn-cluster mode

Comment: This line is weird

Comment: Please can you show the `ScanEngine.getInstance()` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your evidence of it working is seeing **Inside scanning method..** printed out, it won't show up when run on the cluster because that code is executed by the workers, not the driver.

You're going to have to go over the code in forensic detail, with an open mind and try to find why the job has no output.  Usually when a job works on local mode but not on a cluster it is because of some subtlety in where the code is executed, or where output is recorded.

There's too much clipped code to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Edited to address the actual question!

Comment: I am returning an iterator from the method that is called from mappartition.... I have not posted the complete program here. Also i am using a mutable List collection to hold multiple results that are returned and finally converting that to string using List.mkString("\n") method and then returning it back...I suspect the usage of Mutable collection to be the problem....Your thoughts on this?

Comment: @DILIPKUMAR The use of mutable collection shouldn't cause a problem. Is the `try` statement in `getResponse` preventing an exception being reported?

Comment: Nope. The try statement is followed by a proper catch block and i am printing the stack trace as well..

Comment: thanks for the details....i have fixed the issue....in local mode i am using a config file in the linux machine....now i have modified the scan engine to pick the file from HDFS so that it is available for all the nodes in the cluster where the executors will be running.....

Answer (score 0):

Spark achieves parallelism using the `map` function as well as `mapPartitions`.  The number of partitions determines the amount of parallelism, but each partition will execute independently whether or not you use the `mapPartitions` function.

There are only a few reasons to use `mapPartitions` over `map`; e.g. there isa high initialization cost for a function, but then can call it multiple times such as doing some NLP task on text